# Contact form 7 with qtranslate

Tags: ajax, wordpress, contact-form-7, qtranslate

I am using **qTranslate** for bilingual Wordpress. One problem I have is with **Contact Form 7** contact pages. I need the Arabic texts as options in the Contact 7 form, only when the user is seeing the site in Arabic.

Lets say I have the following:

```
[radio paymethod "VISA" "MASTERCARD" "AMEX"]
```

I need to show these values in Arabic when its Arabic mode. Also need to get the error/success messages in the other languages (ie: when the language is switched).

I tried changing `settings.php` of the plugin. It was

````php
    return (string) $wpcf7_request_uri;```
and now is
```php
    $lang = "&lang=" . qtrans_getLanguage();
    return ((string) $wpcf7_request_uri) . $lang;
````

It changes my url to: `http://example.com/contact-us/&lang=ar#wpcf7-f289-t1-o1` and that results in a 404.

qTranslate has three configs for language.

1. query string
2. pre-Path Mode (puts /en/ in front)
3. en.yoursite.com.
   I am using 2.

Comment: I think the only way is to create new contact form for each language you use. As mention here http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-contact-form-7-contactform-7-qtranslate

Comment: @Rikesh thanks the support thread really helped. But the tip about getting the error/success messages gives 404. As I am using the /en/ style. It will add the language at end of the URI.

Comment: What do you mean by "getting the error/success messages"? Ain't they displayed via Ajax? AFAIK, @Rikesh comment is [the answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/70827/12615).

Comment: creating separate forms especially when the special tags like Radio, Checkbox, combobox etc somes in, is the best solution.

Comment: @brasofilo Look at the link @rickesh gave in his comment. There is a voluntery trick one user posted there. To alter the Ajax request url for language switching. But it passes query string and not working while I am using the URL or form `/en/` or `/ar/`.

Comment: For the sake of clarity, I'd suggest that you add the trick to the Q, what doesn't work and your exact config for qTrans & CF7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution.

The contact forms can be created using a `locale` at the beginning. I contacted the Plugin Author and he [directed to this page](http://contactform7.com/contact-form-in-your-language/)

I also made changes to the `settings.php` of the Contact form 7 as the following:

```php
    function wpcf7_get_request_uri() {
       global $wpcf7_request_uri;
       if (($GLOBALS['q_config']['hide_default_language'] == 1) AND ($GLOBALS['q_config']['default_language'] != $GLOBALS['q_config']['language']))
        return ((string) '/' . $GLOBALS['q_config']['language'] . $wpcf7_request_uri);
    }
```

Comment: Without the above code the error/success message will come in the desired language but the RTL/LTR switching for the language wont happen.